# Modifying strings with source_span package in dartlang?

Tags: dart

I want to transform some parts of my source files with an own transformer in dart. 
I have a dart file as input and i want to edit this file. 
I know that I can get the contents of the file with:

```
  var content = transform.primaryInput.readAsString(encoding: UTF8);
```

from inside transformers. 
I know also how to find the offset in my source where I want to apply some changes.

Is there some kind of "Cursor"-Style editing Package for strings in Dart?
I want to do some kind of (Pseudo-Code!):

```
String sourceString = transform.primaryInput.readAsString(encoding: UTF8);
//SourceFile comes from source_span package, could be wrapped by cursor implementation
SourceFile source = new SourceFile(sourceString);
var cursor = new Cursor(sourceFile);

//.jumpTo(int lineNumber, [int columnNumber])
cursor.jumpTo(30);
//deletes the next two chars
cursor.delete(2);
//adds new text after cursor
cursor.write("Hello World!");
//accept sourceSpans for deletion
cursor.delete(sourceSpanObject)
```

Or is there a better way to change contents of source files in transfomers in dart?